# Event stopPropagation on div <a> child element

Tags: jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

Event stop propagation is not working on my code below:

```
<div id="notif_msg" class="messages" style="display: block;">
<a href="/fotos.php?pag=galeria&amp;view=315" class="message" id="2788">
    <span id="2788" style="color:white;">TRY</span>
</a>
```

then I use this jQuery to stop its event

```
$( '#notif_msg a.message' ).live("click",function( event ) {
       event.stopPropagation();
    });
```

my wild guess here is I'm clicking on my span element rather than the a element. I'm using live event because I'm appending some other `a` element.

Please help.

UPDATE---- this is my ajax to load my notifications dynamically

```
function loadnotif(myid){

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "fragmentos/ajax/loadnotif.php",
            data:{"myid":myid},
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(html)
            {  
                $('#notif_msg').append(html.data);
                if(html.newnot == 1){
                    $('#noti-container').removeClass('noticon');
                    $('#noti-container').addClass('noticon-active');
                }                     
            }                   
      });
}
```

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using ? With newer versions I would recommend using `on` instead of `live`

Comment: im using 1.6 @empiric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are using event delgation, and `live()` will append the handler to the document object which means the event has already reached to top of the tree and there is no more to propagate

You need to bind the handler directly to the element if you want to stop the propagation

```
$('#notif_msg a.message').click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Note: You should be using jQuery < 1.9 for `live` to work, so I'm assuming you are using jQuery < 1.9. But the same principle applies if you use `.on()` for event delegation

Comment: Hi @Arun .still it cannot stop the propagation. i put my jquery under document ready function

Comment: @JohnChristianDeChavez whether those elements are created dynamically

Comment: what should i do now sir @Arun

Comment: @JohnChristianDeChavez it depends on how the elements are created... I think they are created dynamically after the page is loaded.. is it right... also why do you want to stop the propagation

Comment: yah they are created dynamically . i load them using ajax. i want to stop propagation because i want to debug first before proceeding to the specified page

Comment: then in the ajax success method you can add the handler... can you share the ajax method that is loading the elements

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73838/discussion-between-john-christian-de-chavez-and-arun-p-johny).

Comment: @JohnChristianDeChavez what was the problem & solution

Comment: @JohnChristianDeChavez so you were looking at preventing the default action not propogation...

Comment: actually im into propagation. but i really cant make it work. so i used prevent and it gaves me the same thing so i can debug now my process. thanks!